# How fast are baby zombies?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

If the generic movement speed for normal zombies is 0.23, what is for baby zombies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Baby speed boost" [attribute modifier](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Attribute#Modifiers) uses `Operation:1` with value `0.5`. This means that baby zombies have 150% the speed (or "50% more") compared to normal zombies.

As zombies normally have a speed of ~`0.23`, baby zombies have a speed of `0.23 * 1.5 =` **`0.345`**