# Can the speed of a baby zombie be applied to normal zombies?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In a last [post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/293143/how-fast-are-baby-zombies/293147?noredirect=1#comment414046_293147) I was wondering the speed of a baby zombie. The reason for this was to use the information and applied it to create a normal zombie has the same speed as a baby. Before I thought you multiplied [0.5](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Attribute#Modifiers) to the generic movement speed of [0.23](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Attribute#Attributes_available_on_all_living_entities) to get the speed. However I figured there was something wrong with that as the numbers were not consisted.

Comment: May I ask why? I'm a very curious person .

Comment: My reason is stated above.

Comment: Not what i meant (:. But fair enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Baby speed boost" attribute modifier uses `Operation:1` with value `0.5`. This means that baby zombies have 150% the speed (or "50% more") compared to normal zombies.

As zombies normally have a speed of ~`0.23`, baby zombies have a speed of `0.23 * 1.5 =` **`0.345`**

You can summon a zombie with this speed like so:

```
/summon zombie ~ ~ ~ {Attributes:[{Name:generic.movementSpeed,Base:0.345}]}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is i think the answer :

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~1 ~ {Attributes:[{Name:generic.movementSpeed,Base:0.13}]}
```

If this helped i suggest using mcstacker for help :
https://mcstacker.bimbimma.com/mcstacker1.10.php

Comment: You can code block by placing 4 spaces before your code. This doesn't seem correct though, as the summoned zombie has a much higher speed than baby zombies.

Comment: Hmm i must have mixed up the generic speed with the other one... Thanks for tj

Comment: for telling me how to use the code blocks

Comment: I have this completely wrong (=